# Issue comparing string with datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

script is ---

```
 function TimeSpentForFutureDate() {
      var toDate = new Date();
      toDate.setMinutes(0);
      toDate.setSeconds(0);
      toDate.setHours(0);
      toDate.setMilliseconds(0);
  //Here after selecting future date also, this condition is failing.The textbox
      // containing a future date

      if (document.getElementById('<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').value > toDate) {
          var timespent = jPrompt('Enter Time Spent:', '', 'Enter Time Spent', 
          function (r) {
              if (r) {
                 document.getElementById('<%= 
                    hiddenFieldFutureDateSelectTimeSpent.ClientID%>').value = r;
                 jAlert('You entered ' + r);
              }
              else {
                 var todaysDate = new Date();
                 jAlert('You had not entered the Time Spent', 'Message');
              }
              });
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=
                    hiddenFieldFutureDateSelectTimeSpent.ClientID%>').value = 
                    timespent;
                document.getElementById('<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').value = toDate;
            }
        }
```

In the above code I'm checking that if text box 'txtDate' will contain a future date.

[ i.e date greater then today's date it will prompt for entering time spent and then store that time spent into an hidden field.]

I'm not able to convert a string into date time object for comparison. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is that mysterious #txtDate string?

Comment: This is a textBox containing date selected from an calendar extender.

Comment: in which format calendar extender get date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.parse` will do the trick

```
var dateToCovert=document.getElementById('<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').value;
var sDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateToCovert,"MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

the format("MM/dd/yyyy") of course can be changed against your needs

*note:*

make sure `dateToCovert` is not null and it is a valid format

`Date.parse` doesn't work in IE7/8.

Comment: How to put that parse in my code i.e. if (document.getElementById('<%= txtDate.ClientID%>').value > toDate), Any suggestion?

Comment: You should advise against the compatibility, though. `Date.parse` doesn't work in IE7/8.

Comment: And here is a shim for `Date.parse` in case you need the compatibility :) https://gist.github.com/303249